# Customize Django Form fields

Tags: html, django, forms

I am well aware that related questions have been raised on SO before but I still find them insufficient to solve the following problem -

Need to build a form using `django.forms`.Form with all field labels right aligned.

what is currently happening is either the labels get center aligned or the choices come below the labels as shown below:

Liked the food?

- Great
- Okay
- Bad

What I want is

```
 Liked the food:   

                 o Great
                 o Okay
                 o Bad
           Dish: 
       Beverage:
 Membership ID*:
```

Most widget customization doesn't seem to affect the field LABEL alignment

Update [after adityasdarma1 answer]

I can always skip the django forms altogether and write everything in HTML
but I want to code as less as possible in HTML while achieving the desired alignment.

I expected that django will allow me to set such alignment at global level.

If I could access the description label and the input GUI element and control the format in HTML, even that is fine.

The closest I have come is following. Can anybody suggest me what changes in the code below are needed to right aligned labels.

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div>
    <label for="{{ field.label }}">{{ field.label_tag }}
    {% if field.field.required %}<span class="special_class">*</span>{% endif %}</label>

    {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Quickest way to fix one form's layout is indeed manual html, but if you'd like a more systematic approach to customize all your forms, you should definitively have a look at [crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tr and td did the trick (code snippet shared below)

```
<table >
    {% for field in form %}
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="{{ field.label }}" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ field }}
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 4):

You must render the form manually and give proper classes. Read [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I have tried to be clearer to the point I have achieved. Just looking for THE tweak that will enable the above code to get desired effect.

Comment: Change `{{ field.label_tag }}` to `{{ field.label }}`

and in `for` attribute, change it to `{{ field.auto_id }}`

Comment: Updated link as for Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template

Answer (score 0):

Django offers a few options for customizing your form layout. Check out the official Django documentation on [rendering forms manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) and using [form templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates)