# Show all foreign key fields in Django admin create page

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-keys, django-admin

I am new with Django and mysql so i have a question:

- I am using admin model for my first django web app
- I have 2 of model like that:

```
class Report(models.Model):
     week = models.CharField()
     customer_account = models.CharField()
     release_name = models.ForeignKey(ReleaseInformation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')

class ReleaseInformation(models.Model):
    release_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    process_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Constant.QUALITY, default=None)
```

With release name is ForeignKey from ReleaseInformation
So in create a new model of Report, I can see and select Release name.
My question is: How can I display all fields of ReleaseInformation() When I select a object of it from create Report page
Ex: as in the picture, it will show all field of Tool when i select Tool
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFCP1.png)

How can I do it?

Comment: You need to customize the `__str__` method of your `ReleaseInformation` class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not really what i want. I want when select release_name, after that the other field will display row by row with title, like: release_date: {value} process_status: {value} Do you have any idea about it ? many tks!!!

Comment: You will need to customize your form and add this information in your template. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757110/customize-django-form-fields

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the string representation of each ReleaseInformation instance with the `__str__()` method like so:

```py
class ReleaseInformation(models.Model):
    release_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    process_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Constant.QUALITY, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.release_name} {self.release_date} {self.process_status}'
```

You can find more info here:
[Djando Documentation | Model instance reference | str method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#str)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not really what i want. I want when select release_name, after that the other field will display row by row with title, like:
release_date: {value}
process_status: {value}
Do you have any idea about it ? many tks!!!

Comment: The way I mentioned you can kind of do that by changing the `__str__` function like return f'release_date: {self.release_date} process_status: {self.process_status}\t release_name: {self.release_name}'

Comment: I am not sure I understand where you want the columns. Inside a choise box I dont think it is possible. If you have standard choices for process_status with some playing around you can make it look like columns with each variable starting at the same point